# SQL Select in stored procedure existing values from a row: Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure that works, but it is not efficient nor elegant.  Is there a better way to capture the three values @_score, @_comment, and @_note through a single query instead of three queries?

---

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateScore]
            @sqaeid nvarchar(30), 
            @username nvarchar(30),
            @scoreid nvarchar(30),
            @score nvarchar(30),
            @comment nvarchar(max),
            @note nvarchar(max)
AS
/* Capture the existing three values that will get
   overwritten with new data */
declare @_score as nvarchar(30)
declare @_comment as nvarchar(max)
declare @_note as nvarchar(max)

/******************************************************************/
/* Is there a more elegant, and efficient, way to do this?        */
/******************************************************************/
Set @_score = (Select score from tScore where score_id=@scoreid)
Set @_comment = (Select comment from tScore where score_id=@scoreid)
Set @_note = (Select note from tScore where score_id=@scoreid)
/******************************************************************/

/* Update the table row with the new data */
UPDATE tScore Set score=@score, comment=@comment, note=@note  WHERE score_id=@scoreid

/* Generate a log entry that will capture the old data and the new data in
   case we want to rollback to the previous values */
INSERT into tLog 
VALUES (@sqaeid, @username, GETDATE(), 'updateScore', 
        'score_id', @scoreid, 'new score', @score, 
        'new comment', @comment, 'new note', @note, 
        'old score', @_score, 'old comment', @_comment,
        'old note', @_note);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateScore]
            @sqaeid nvarchar(30), 
            @username nvarchar(30),
            @scoreid nvarchar(30),
            @score nvarchar(30),
            @comment nvarchar(max),
            @note nvarchar(max)
AS

UPDATE tScore 
    Set   score = @score
        , comment = @comment
        , note = @note  
Output 
    @sqaeid, @username, GETDATE(), 'updateScore', 
        'score_id', @scoreid, 
        'new score', inserted.score, 
        'new comment', inserted.comment, 
        'new note', inserted.note, 
        'old score', deleted.score, 
        'old comment', deleted.comment,
        'old note', deleted.note
Into tlog
WHERE score_id = @scoreid
```

Comment: Both solutions provided are good.  Since the tLog file has an identity field the first solution works completely, but the second solution is the most elegant and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replace your three `SET`s with:

```
SELECT  @_score     = score,
        @_comment   = comment
        @_note      = note
FROM tScore
WHERE score_id = @scoreid;
```